# MongoDB : Using the value 1 for Filter Fields

Tags: mongodb

I am working on a existing code in which they are using Mongo DB  with Java EE.

Under which in some case for filteration purposes , they are using the hard coded value as 1 .

```
BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject(SEC_TYPE, "A");

BasicDBObject Fields = new BasicDBObject("date", 1);
returnFields.put("unisymbol", 1);
returnFields.put("symbol", 1);


DBCursor cursor = coll.find(query, Fields);
```

For example if you see the above query the Fields such as date , unisymbol and symbol are hardcoded to 1 .

Please let me know what does ,  putting the value "1" aganist the filed mean exactly ??

Comment: It means that the field will be projected into the resulting documents, putting a 0 does the opposite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means, "retrieve value only for this field". So, this query:

```
db.users.find({}, {firstname: 1, lastname: 1})
```

will get only two fields, first name and last name. It won't get email, address and other fields.

Answer (score 1):

It is used for projection: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/read-operations/#result-projections whereby the fields of the document are being filtered out. In this case `1` against that field means to include it and `0` mens to omit it.

So the code above includes `date`, `unisymbol`, `symbol` and `_id`. It includes the `_id` since that has to be explicitly removed from the result via:

```
returnFields.put("_id", 0);
```